# How to transfer two wordpress websites to new one

Tags: wordpress

I have two websites abc.com and xyz.com. I buy new domain efg.com. Now I want to transfer complete data using plugins from both websites to the new one. These are ecommerce websites. I try to export xml files but it failed everytime
Can anybody tell me how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into why the exporting or importing of the xml's failed.  Another Approach would be to access the data directly in the database and "diump" it from there using hand written MySQL queries or the PhpMyAdmin interface.

Some typical reasons why the import/export of xmls fails in WordPress:
The same theme and/or plugins aren't being used
The theme and/or plugins aren't exporting all their data.

The former is easy to fix.  The solution to the later is to do manual exports of data from the database using MySQL queries or the PhpMyAdmin interface.

Good luck!

Comment: ok.. it is ecommerce website so does it export all the data as it is the old website? can you please give me any tutorial link for this.. It will be more helpful for me